# Creating a 2D skeleton animation system for use with Panda3D

Tags: 2d, animation, skeletal-animation, python

Hey. I want to be able to create a system for 2D skeletal animation in my game. I'm using [panda3d](http://www.panda3D.org) as my game engine. I'd like to be able to make simple bone structures and skin them with my sprites. I would prefer to do this with straight code and algorithms, but if I have to use a 3D modeler or something, then I can try to (I didn't do a great job last time I tried using Blender... >.<)

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure about panda3d, but I am pretty sure you need to start thinking about the algorithms and structure / pattern of making bones then moving them, then skinning them with your sprites.

Once these concepts are strong in your mind, you should then apply them to panda3d (what ever language / scripting it uses) or look up specific panda3d existing 2d animation systems using bones.

Similar to - how to learn 2d animation

[How to learn 2d animation?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-learn-2d-animation)