# Sprite Animation Software That Works With Cocos2D

Tags: sprites, cocos2d

So the title basically says it all. I'm looking for software that would help me to create sprite animations that I could use with cocos2d by allowing me to pose a a sprite and the software create key-frames between the sprites( basic tweening ).

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-learn-2d-animation). The answers cover a lot of possible software. Btw. there's no special requirements for Cocos2D. You can use any animation software that renders to image-frames. You can then use these directly or use a packing tool to create sprite-sheets...

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you need the Gamedev Animation Studio.
I use it to animate sprites. This tool  interpolate the animation  between keyframes by various characteristics of sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Spriter](http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm)? It's currently in alpha, but their forums have plugins available for cocos2d.

Answer (score -1):

[Pivot](http://www.gamefront.com/files/14447601/Pivot-3-beta/) is one of the sprite animation software. you can always use photoshop